# (TypeError: 'module' object is not callable) while using chromedriver of selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the following code

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.chrome(r"C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
```

and i am getting the following error:

```
"C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\book appt\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/book appt/venv/book appt.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/book appt/venv/book appt.py", line 3, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.chrome(r"C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\chromedriver.exe")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

i have selenium and pip installed already and also chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function `chrome`, it should be

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\chromedriver.exe")
```

Also make sure that you downloaded a chrome driver with version lower than or equal to your installed chrome browser or that will make it fail too.